# Google Docs Issue

Tags: google-sheets

I have a document on Google Sheets that lists the start time and the end time.

```
 Start   End       Duration
 11:59  15:30       03:31
 16:25  17:16       00:51
 17:50  21:35       03:45
 20:37  00:31       03:54
```

I also get the duration of the event by subtracting the end from the first. When I try to total the duration column, I often get a large negative number.

My other issue is that I am trying to filter data and sum durations by dates. Say, I want to get the total duration for the last 30 days on a summary page. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It could be because of the format of your `Duration` Column. I have seen if the format it different the `SUM` or `=` will work weirdly.

Comment: What should they be?

Comment: Numbers i suppose!

Comment: I should add that I have used Automatic Format type. When I change the Duration column to a Duration type the days where the entry is in the next day, the Duration shows up negative. When I use automatic format they show with the correct value.

Comment: What is your formula for the duration column?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with negative number can be because when you sum, for example your last row:
00:31 - 20:37, do not forget excel does not know the date of it, so if it considers the same date, you will get negative numbers: 00:31 am < 20:37 PM

Ideally, when you work with sum of times, you want to specify the date in order to avoid it.

You can select Date Time on Format > Number > Date Time and add the date for each time
So it would be:
Start:
12/30/2017 20:37:00
End:
12/31/2017 0:31:00
Duration:
3:54

Now to sum the duration according to its date, create a new Column called Date. 
I added a table for reference:

[Table for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ1dB.png)

You can extract the date from Date Time using =DATEVALUE(A2) for column D.

Now you will use a SUMIFS:
=SUMIFS(C2:C5,D2:D5, ">"&DATE(2017,12,1),D2:D5,"<"&DATE(2018,1,1))
It will sum the duration if the date is in month December

Comment: Okay, I see the issue. Is their a way I can simply tell it to assume it's the next day. Can I just add 24 if it's negative.

Comment: @MarquisTaylor `=IF(B2<A2,1,0) + B2 - A2`

Comment: Scott's solution is a good way, or you coukld do: `=IF(B2<A2, A2 - B2, B2 - A2)`